# Replace any character outside of the English alphabet in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace any character outside of the English alphabet?

For example, 'abcdükl*m' replaced with a ' ' would be 'abcd kl m'

Comment: What did you try? Which resource did you consult? Do you know about "negated character classes"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the regex `[^a-zA-Z]`:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', mystring)
```

Some info: the `a-zA-Z` are character ranges that indicate all the lowercase and uppercase letter, respectively, and the caret `^` at the beginning of the character class indicates negation, e.g. "anything except these".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're trying to normalize text, see my link under "[Comprehensive character replacement module in python for non-unicode and non-ascii for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944604/442650)".

`unicodedata` has a `normalize` method that can gracefully degrade text for you:

```
import unicodedata
def gracefully_degrade_to_ascii( text ):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',text).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Full Docs - http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html

If you're trying to just strip out non-ASCII chars, the negated character set regex that others mentioned is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `[^a-zA-Z]` and replace with ' '

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> print ''.join(x if x in string.ascii_letters else ' ' for x in u'abcdükl*m') 
abcd kl m
```